# Keep getting "invalid email"

Tags: php, jquery, validation

I keep getting invalid email. Please help! I am new to forms. I have a form in html action is send info to this php. ot sure what the problem is but does it matter if there is two email validation? I have this php page and a jQuery, both validating the email. not sure if that is the affecting this.

```
<?php 
$errors = '';
$myemail = 'something@something.com';
if(empty($_POST['contact_name'])  || 
   empty($_POST['contact_email']) || 
   empty($_POST['contactcomment']))
{
    $errors .= "\n Error: all fields are required";
}

$name = $_POST['name']; 
$email_address = $_POST['email']; 
$message = $_POST['message']; 

if(filter_var($email_address,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false)
{
    echo 'Email is not valid';
}
else
{

}
```

Comment: see working example http://codepad.viper-7.com/sly5OZ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're checking to see if `$_POST['contact_email']` is empty but passing the value of `$_POST['email']` to `$email_address`, I'm assuming that `contact_email` is the one you want since that is the one you're checking to see if its empty or not. So email will either be `empty` or `something@something` none of which is a valid email.

So simply change:

```
$email_address = $_POST['email'];
```

to:

```
$email_address = $_POST['contact_email'];
```

Comment: The same thing goes for $name and probably $message also, which I guess is what you want `$_POST['contactcomment']` for.

Comment: OMG!!!! Thanks a lot! Right in front of my eyes and I couldn't see it. Almost 7am, working all night must be affect my eyes. Thanks a lot @Daniel Figueroa

Comment: Happens to all of us, now go get some sleep! :)

Comment: Well now that I know its working I could sleep calmly, and not get nightmare filled with numbers and letters. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `.com`

```
$myemail = 'something@something.com';
```

and check your

`echo $email_address = $_POST['email'];` You are using this value in your function.

in `if` condition you are using `$_POST['contact_email']`, Please note : one is `email` and other is `contact_email`

Comment: That error was just made right now changing the email. But its something else!

Comment: @user2090897 : check your `echo $email_address = $_POST['email'];` value

Comment: Hey thanks a lot! That was exactly the problem. So simple yet when you have been working all night, you being to fail in the small tasks.

Comment: @user2090897 : Cool, accept the answer, some one may find it usefull.

Answer (score 0):

`something@something` is not a valid email. The function is working correctly, the email you've input is invalid.

Unless you're providing something different in `$_POST['email_address']`;

Comment: Where do you see `something@something` without `.com` in the question?